# Desktop alert does not work in sub methods

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using "Growl Alike WPF Notifications" by Ivan Leonenko (@[codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499241/Growl-Alike-WPF-Notifications)).

This works when I am adding notifications within my MainWindow.
When I add notifications within sub methods the alerts do not appear.

This is my working code:

```
    private User user;
    private readonly GrowlNotifiactions growlNotifications = new GrowlNotifiactions();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Sample output GrowlNotification works
        addAlertDesktop("Hello #1", "Lorem Ipsum");
        addAlertDesktop("Hello #2", "Lorem Ipsum");
        addAlertDesktop("Hello #3", "Lorem Ipsum");
    }

    private void addAlertDesktop(string title, string message)
    {
        growlNotifications.AddNotification(new Notification { Title = title, ImageUrl = "pack://application:,,,/Resources/notification-icon.png", Message = message });
    }
```

This is the code that does not work:

```
    private User user;
    private readonly GrowlNotifiactions growlNotifications = new GrowlNotifiactions();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void addAlertDesktop(string title, string message)
    {
        growlNotifications.AddNotification(new Notification { Title = title, ImageUrl = "pack://application:,,,/Resources/notification-icon.png", Message = message });
    }

    private void setTimer(User user) {
        Timer timer = new Timer(5000);
        systemTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => OnTimerElapsed(user);
        systemTimer.AutoReset = true;
        systemTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(User user)
    {
        checkUser(user);
    }

    private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        User currentUser = (User)sender;
        checkUser(user);
    }

    private void checkUser(User user)  {
        setTimer(user);
        addAlertDesktop("Hello #1", "Lorem Ipsum");
        user.checked = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Ensure you're not getting an exception - since you're inside a `Timer` callback, [any exceptions may be getting swallowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718598/throwing-exceptions-in-callback-method-for-timers)

Comment: Yes, there is a thrown exception. But I do not get it. "From this collection view type no changes are supported to the "Source Collection" if they are not done by a dispatcher thread out."

Comment: Making an assumption that when you call addAlertDesktop it changes the UI.  If this is the case, this may fail as the timer callback is asynchronous and therefore not on the UI thread.  If this is the case, take a look at DispatcherTimer

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't like having notifications added from a thread on which it wasn't created.  Not sure about WPF, but in winforms you'd check `InvokeRequired` and use `Invoke` if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an issue whereby you are trying to update the UI from a background thread; try replacing your Timer with a [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = 5000;
timer.Tick += (sender, e) => OnTimerElapsed(user);
timer.Start();
```

If you wanted to keep using the Timer class you can still marshal the subsequent code on to the dispatcher:

Change addAlertDesktop to:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() = > growlNotifications.AddNotification(new Notification { Title = title, ImageUrl = "pack://application:,,,/Resources/notification-icon.png", Message = message }));
```

Comment: I have a class called TaskTimer that implements System.Timers.Timer where milliseconds are passed: public TaskTimer(int interval) : base(interval); The DispatcherTimer does not accept the seconds as int. How do I have to customize it?

Comment: I've updated answer to show a way to keep using the Timer class

Comment: Using the dispatchertimer you can set the interval in seconds like this: timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)